# On mobile view home page not redirecting using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that I have built;

http://ryanotoolecollett.com/

That when resized to less than (<768px) or loaded when the window width is <768px it should redirect to;

http://ryanotoolecollett.com/portfolio

I have deployed this site on a linode server and was testing it with the ip address before hand and it was working on both mobile's and pc's.

However now after linking the domain, the redirect works on pc's when resizing and loading <768px however on mobile devices it renders a blank page (i.e. `landing-page:display-none;`). But this is not meant to happen.

Here is the jquery code that I have written for this (it is in my document ready function)

```
 $(window).on('load resize',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  if($(window).width() < 768 && window.location.href == 'http://ryanotoolecollett.com'){

   window.location.href = "http://ryanotoolecollett.com/portfolio";

 }
```

});

Comment: Do you know if the redirect is being fired i.e. the conditions of your if statement are being met?

Comment: @AlanBuchanan When I go to a mobile device lets say an iphone, I type in the url and it should (as mentioned it did before) redirect to `/portfolio` straight away.

Comment: Instead of pointing out to your website, you should better provice an [mcve](/help/mcve) that reproduce your issue. This will be more clear for us and avoid your post to be downvoted or closed because of advertisement: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349795/6320039

Comment: @UlysseBN Should I make edits? I definitely do not want to promote anything, I'm still a noob learning!

Comment: I'm sure you're not, don't worry! Read about the [mcve](/help/mcve) page and make your own. Two good pages to start with are also Stack Overflow's [tour](/tour) and the [how to ask help](/help/how-to-ask). Though your question is already pretty well written IMO.

Comment: @UlysseBN will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement you're doing :

```
$(window).width() < 768 && window.location.href == 'http://ryanotoolecollett.com'
```

Which is fine, but `window.location.href` actually, equals `http://ryanotoolecollett.com/` notice the forward slash at the end.

Comment: This is probably why I originally had it working with the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
if(window.innerWidth<786)
 window.location.href = "http://ryanotoolecollett.com/portfolio";
```